# Ubuntu can't find Arrogant Bastard Vortex mouse

Tags: mouse

I dualboot win7 and Ubuntu and I've gotten a new mouse, "Arrogant Bastard Vortex". But when in Ubuntu, the mouse simply doesn't respond. I've tried different USB-ports and trying to unplug and replug it but it doesn't help. I'm not very familiar with ubuntu yet so what should I do?

I've figured out that the mouse give rise to the following line when I execute lsusb:

Bus 001 Device 007 ID 04d9:a081 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.

Comment: Can you post the output of lsusb?

Comment: Not an answer, but here's a bug related to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1247497

Answer (score 0):

Try with reinstalling the mouse driver:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-mouse && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

Comment: It didn't help.